# Sending messenger message to all members of a facebook group which I am admin of?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I am administrating a facebook group. I want to send all the members a messenger message (doesn't matter now if it's one group message or a single message to each person; though having both options would be great). How do I do this?

I found [these instructions](https://help.goodreads.com/s/article/how-can-I-broadcast-a-message-to-all-members-of-my-group). I navigated to  my group's main page and click "members" in the menu. But I got stuck in step 3: I don't see the "broadcast a message to all members" link or button anywhere on the page. Did Facebook remove it since?

I also tried to message the group directly from messenger.com, but I cannot add it to the "To:" field. It allows to add only people and Pages.

How do I do this?